# Oracle 19 - Select rows with json column with any value or values that match array element(s)

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have an Oracle table (version 19) that have three columns:
`id` - integer
`author` - varchar(2)
`associations` - JSON

Each Json is a collection of array elements.
For example associations:

```json
{ country: "country1" ,
  booknames: ["book 1", "book 2", ... ]
}
```

The names of the books are to be searched for each author and I want to return only the authors that are associated with certain books.

I need to search for rows that have multiple books for each author that they can be associated with.
Example: need to select author with booknames that match: "book 1" OR "book 5"

If anyone can help that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I did some reading and found this to get to my solution
[Oracle docs 19](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/json-path-expressions.html#GUID-AEBAD813-99AB-418A-93AB-F96BC1658618)

`json_exists` with `like_regex` satisfies the majority of my request.

The only catch is that it is like contains so it will match book with names that have a common part for example "Tale" and "Tale of two cities" but I am looking for word boundary.

Will keep updating this as I get this resolved.

Comment: Updated: adding like_regex "^(Tale)$" for just the book with name "Tale" and add the "|" for multiple booknames (strings) solves my issue, thanks to everyone who spent some time for reading and taking their time to help me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `json_exists` condition with an **`in`** condition. Like shown below.

Data setup:

```
create table sample_data
( id           number       primary key
, author       varchar2(30)
, associations clob         check(associations is json)
);

insert into sample_data (id, author, associations) values (
1001, 'Joe', 
to_clob('{country:"country1",booknames:["book 1","book 2","book 5"]}')
);

insert into sample_data (id, author, associations) values (
1128, 'Ann', 
to_clob('{country:"country1",booknames:["book 1","book 3","book 8"]}')
);

insert into sample_data (id, author, associations) values (
1156, 'Ali', 
to_clob('{country:"country6",booknames:["book 9","book 5","book 3"]}')
);

insert into sample_data (id, author, associations) values (
1438, 'Lee', 
to_clob('{country:"country4",booknames:["book 1","book 2","book 6"]}')
);

commit;
```

Query and output:

```
select id, author
from   sample_data
where  json_exists(associations, '$?(@.booknames[*] in ("book 3", "book 5"))')
;


  ID  AUTHOR
----  ------
1001  Joe
1128  Ann
1156  Ali
```